# if there any better way to read bb function souce code.i was very faint 

Tags: python

```
in python ,if 

a.py
from b import bb
bb()

b.py
from c import cc
def bb():
  do someting else
  cc()

c.py
from d import dd
def cc():
  do someting else
  dd()


d.py
from e import ee
def dd():
  do someting else
  ee()

e.py
from f import ff
def ee():
  do someting else
  ff()
```

to Understood bb function,i must open 5 file,i was very faint .

if there any better way to read bb function.(a tools to read source code better)

thanks

Comment: what? the question doesnt make sense? are you asking if there is a faster way to read the doco?

Comment: Do you mean you're getting tired of *typing* it?

Comment: @Chii ,no ,my mean is better way to read code in file.

Comment: @zjm1126:  Are you having trouble opening the files?  Or do you not like the *design* of function `bb`?  If you don't like the *design* of the function -- depends on too many other files -- that's not a question, that's a complaint.  Talk to the author of `bb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to import the `ff` function from the `f` module would be to use an import statement in your program:

```
from f import ff
ff(...)
```

Or you could use the form:

```
import f
f.ff(...)
```

**EDIT:**

If you are looking for tools to better read/navigate through the source code, I recommend creating a `tags` file for your source code tree (using either `ctags` or `ptags.py`).

You then point a capable editor (like Vim or Emacs) to that file, and use the editor's features to navigate your way through the code. For instance, using Vim, `Ctrl-]` jumps to the definition of the symbol under the cursor.

What editor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Whoever wrote the code for file a.py should have just written

a.py

from f import ff

I mean isn't that what OO and modules are supposed to do: make code reusable?

Or maybe this is an example of obfuscation by tiresomeness.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already using an IDE, you might like to give [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/screenshots/) a try